# How can I display syntax highlighting on a file?

Tags: command-line, cat, highlighting

Is there a variant of `cat` that outputs syntax-highlighted lines of code when used on a source file?

An idea: maybe `vi[m]` or another editor can be asked to dump the syntax-highlighted contents of said files to `stdout` and exit immediately?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Passing the file through [`pygmentize`](http://pygments.org/)`-f terminal` will attempt to detect the type from the filename and highlight it appropriately.

Comment: Is that the Star Trek: Deep Space Nine font in their logo? If it is that's awesome.

Comment: Available as package `python-pygments` on Debian.

Comment: I found `alias pcat="pygmentize -f terminal256 -O style=native -g"` to be a nice solution

Comment: also available via `pip install pygments`

Comment: @MikaelÖhman I actually found it easier to alias `cat` to a function `pcat` that took the filename as an argument, and output that to `less`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821495/how-do-i-include-parameters-in-a-bash-alias

Comment: Actually it must be `cat code.extension | pygmentize -f terminal -l extension`.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman Thanks, the `-O style=native` made it more readable on dark terminals

Answer (score 15):

The [Source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/s/src-highlite/source-highlight.html) package is shipped with the esc.outlang output language definition, which highlights with ANSI escape sequences.

A handy wrapper `src-hilite-lesspipe.sh` is also included in the package, so displaying highlighted output in the terminal is just `src-hilite-lesspipe.sh source.file`.

Actually `src-hilite-lesspipe.sh`'s primary reason is to help automating the use of `source-highlight` with `less`. You just set:

```
export LESSOPEN="| /path/to/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s"
export LESS=' -R '
```

Then any `less source.file` will show highlighted source code. (Code in unknown language will pass through unaltered. Highlighting will be also skipped in case of redirected content, like `less < source.file`.)

Comment: Nice, thank you for taking the time to write up this answer

Answer (score 7):

[Highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.php) is simple to use and faster than `pygmentize`

Comment: Just don't forget to use `-O ansi`: unlike `pygmentize`, `highlight` outputs HTML by default.

Answer (score 2):

I use `vimcat`.

https://github.com/ofavre/vimcat

[image: vimcat example]

It looks good enough for me.

Comment: I like this idea to use my existing Vim highlighting, just wish the utility worked on all *nix and was available for MacOS via Homebrew!

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Mikael Öhman's comment on @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer, I wrote this Python program to use `pygments` if possible or else use `cat`.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from argparse import ArgumentParser
import subprocess
import os
import os.path


def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='cat alternative that uses ANSI characters')
    parser.add_argument('file', help='the file to print out the contents of', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if not os.path.isfile(args.file):
        parser.error(f'file not found: {args.file}')
    cat = False
    result = subprocess.run(('pygmentize -f terminal256 -O style=native ' + args.file).split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    if result.stderr:
        cat = True
    commands = {
        True: 'cat ',
        False: 'pygmentize -f terminal256 -O style=native '
    }
    os.system(commands[cat] + args.file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```