# Colorized `cat` for source and script files?

Tags: terminal, cat, text, application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I display syntax highlighting on a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19439/how-can-i-display-syntax-highlighting-on-a-file)

Is there any application like `cat`, but with color output?

I'd like to view my files with colors like in any IDE's editor.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/84426/are-there-any-options-to-let-cat-output-with-color

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is tool [source-highlight](https://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/).

Alias example:

```
alias ccat="source-highlight --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i"
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm a fan of [ccze](http://freecode.com/projects/ccze), personally.

Comment: FYI, it's not available in CentOS 8 epel-release.

Answer (score 2):

[Vim](http://www.vim.org/) is always a good option. Plus then you can make quick edits as needed.

Comment: I like the [`vimpager`](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager) project for this.