# How can i colorize cat output including unknown filetypes in b&w?

Tags: colors, cat, source-highlight

I like the colors I have in `vim`. Can I get my output similarly colorized when I do a `cat`?

I like that I can use the colorize tool as in [Colorized `cat` for source and script files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39652/colorized-cat-for-source-and-script-files?rq=1). I would like that to be my standard for `cat`, e.g. I create an alias:

```
alias cat="source-highlight --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i"
```

However if the file type is unknown, say `.gitignore` then this will return:

```
$ cat .gitignore_global
source-highlight: could not find a language definition for input file .gitignore
```

How could I have the command do a `source-highlight` `cat` version if it is a recognized file type and otherwise just do a standard black and white `cat` of the file?

One option is to have the alias be `ccat` but I'd prefer to have it replace `cat` itself if possible.

It would also be nice to be able to use wildcards, e.g. `cat *.rb` (or even `ccat *.rb`)?  Currently that gives:

```
$ ccat *.rb
Please, use one of the two syntaxes for invocation: 
source-highlight [OPTIONS]... -i input_file -o output_file
source-highlight [OPTIONS]... [FILES]...
```

and it would be great to be able to do:

```
ls *.rb | xargs ccat # (or cat)
```

the same way I can do:

```
ls *.rb | xargs cat
```

Currently I get:

```
$ ls *.rb | xargs ccat
xargs: ccat: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What would you like the colors to be dictated by? Log files or source files? It's difficult to colorize non-standard output. But there are ways.

Comment: +1 By whether or not source-highlight can colorize that file type.

Comment: 'sudo nano <file>' worked a treat too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you could do something like the following script (untested):

```
#!/bin/sh

for fn in "$@"; do
    source-highlight --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i $fn 2>/dev/null || /bin/cat $fn
done
```

This does a few things:

- iterates through each command line argument
- tries to run `source-highlight`, redirecting error output to `/dev/null`
- if `source-highlight` fails, then run regular `/bin/cat`

You put this script in a file named `cdc` for example, then `alias cat=cdc`.

#### As a function

You can adapt the above script into a Bash function call which can then be incorporated into your dot files like so:

```
cdc() { 
  for fn in "$@"; do 
    source-highlight --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i $fn 2>/dev/null || /bin/cat $fn;
  done 
}
```

Edit (Michael) for some reason trying to use `ccat` for the function name didn't work but `cdc` did!

Comment: + I like the approach. Any way to avoid having the script though?  I try to avoid having 'dependencies' in my working setup so I can switch and setup machines easily.  I try to limit myself to my 'dotfiles', e.g. `.bashrc`, `.bash_aliases`, etc.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - you could make this a function. See my edits.

Comment: Thanks for this example BTW, I'm adding it to my environment!

Comment: you are very welcome SO knowledge rocks!

Comment: hmmm, but I get `-bash: /home/durrantm/.bashrc: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: For some reason `ccat` gives that error in new shells but all other aliases such as `colcat` or `cccat` work!

Comment: I'm going to update it to catc  weird problem!

Comment: In the end I found cdc easiest to type for the function name.