# How can I colorize head, tail and less, same as I've done with cat?

Tags: colors, tail, function, head

I've got 'color cat' working nicely, thanks to others
(see [How can i colorize cat output including unknown filetypes in b&w?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100841/how-can-i-colorize-cat-output-including-unknown-filetypes-in-bw?rq=1)).

In my `.bashrc`:

```
cdc() {
  for fn in "$@"; do
  source-highlight --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i $fn 2>/dev/null || /bin/cat $fn;
  done
}
alias cat='cdc' # To be next to the cdc definition above.
```

I'd like to be able to use this technique for other functions like head, tail and less.

How could I do that for all four functions?  Any way to generalize the answer?

I have an option for `gd` doing `git diff` using

```
gd() { 
   git diff -r --color=always "$@"
}
```

Comment: I've also tried multitail and grc but they're not working well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
for cmd in cat head tail; do
  cmdLoc=$(type $cmd | awk '{print $3}')
  eval "
    $cmd() { 
      for fn in \"\$@\"; do 
        source-highlight --failsafe --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i \"\$fn\" | 
            $cmdLoc - 
      done 
    }
  "
done
```

You can condense it like this:

```
for cmd in cat head tail; do
    cmdLoc=$(type $cmd |& awk '{print $3}')
    eval "$cmd() { for fn in \"\$@\"; do source-highlight --failsafe --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i \"\$fn\" | $cmdLoc - ; done }"
done
```

#### Example

With the above in a shell script, called `tst_ccmds.bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash

for cmd in cat head tail; do
    cmdLoc=$(type $cmd |& awk '{print $3}')
  eval "$cmd() { for fn in \"\$@\"; do source-highlight --failsafe --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i \"\$fn\" | $cmdLoc - ; done }"
done

type cat
type head
type tail
```

When I run this, I get the functions set as you'd asked for:

```
$ ./tst_ccmds.bash
cat () 
{ 
    for fn in "$@";
    do
        source-highlight --failsafe --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i "$fn" 2> /dev/null | /bin/cat - ;
    done
}
head is a function
head () 
{ 
    for fn in "$@";
    do
        source-highlight --failsafe --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i "$fn" 2> /dev/null | /usr/bin/head - ;
    done
}
tail is a function
tail () 
{ 
    for fn in "$@";
    do
        source-highlight --failsafe --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i "$fn" 2> /dev/null | /usr/bin/tail -;
    done
}
```

#### In action

When I use these functions in my shell (`source ./tst_ccmds.bash`) they work as follows:

*cat*

[image: cat ss]

*head*

[image: head ss]

*tail*

[image: tail ss]

*plain text*

[image: txt ss]

#### What's the trick?

The biggest trick, and I would call it more of a hack, is the use of a dash (`-`) as an argument to `cat`, `head`, and `tail` through a pipe which forces them to output the content that came from `source-highlight` through STDIN of the pipe. This bit:

```
...STDOUT -i "$fn" | /usr/bin/head - ....
```

The other trick is using the `--failsafe` option of `source-highlight`:

```
   --failsafe
          if no language definition is found for the input, it  is  simply
          copied to the output
```

This means that if a language definition is not found, it acts like `cat`, simply copying its input to the standard output.

#### Note about aliases

This function will fail if any of `head`,`tail` or `cat` are aliases because the result of the `type` call will not point to the executable. If you need to use this function with an alias (for example, if you want to use `less` which requires the `-R` flag to colorize) you will have to delete the alias and add the aliased command separately:

```
less(){
     for fn in "$@"; do 
       source-highlight --failsafe --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i "$fn" |
          /usr/bin/less -R || /usr/bin/less -R "$fn"; done
}
```

Comment: +1 for the function as a variable trick but this won't run `head` or `tail` on the files, it will color-cat them and only run `head` if the file type is unknown. I think the OP wants to run a _colored_ `head`, `tail` etc.

Comment: @terdon - ah, thanks for pointing that out. Do you think he wants to head/tail the output of source-highlight? That appears to work, if you pipe it to `tail` or `head`.

Comment: yes, that's what I understood. Something like `source-highlight --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i "$fn" | $cmd || $cmd`. I would have edited but I wasn't sure if that syntax works.

Comment: @terdon - can you double check my changes? Seems to work now.

Comment: Works fine here, added to my `.bashrc` I think this is going to be one of my favorites!

Comment: Worked interactively but when I tried to add it to my `.bashrc` it gives me `-bash: eval: line 136: syntax error near unexpected token `in'
-bash: eval: line 136: `in'
-bash: eval: line 136: syntax error near unexpected token `in'
-bash: eval: line 136: `in'` even though pasting it directly works ok

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - I'd have to see line 136. You have an eval there or something else?

Comment: To be able to pipe to them (progoutx | tail) I added a condition to the functions. works fine including less!! Thanks!      
if [ \$# -eq 0 ]; then
            source-highlight --failsafe --out-format=esc -o STDOUT | $cmdLoc - 
        fi

Comment: For `less` you can actually use the LESSOPEN variable. I've got it with pygmentize like this: `export LESSOPEN='|pygmentize -gf terminal -O style=emacs %s'`