# How can I make source-highlight colorize .dotfiles by default?

Tags: shell-script, colors, function, dot-files, source-highlight

Normally when I cat a file like this

[image]

it's hard to read without colorizing.

I've managed to get `cat` to use source-highlight like this:

```
cdc() {
  for fn in "$@"; do
    source-highlight --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i $fn 2>/dev/null || /bin/cat $fn
  done; }; alias cat='cdc'
```

which now produces the following for a recognized file extension - .sh in this case:

[image]

However without the .sh, e.g. if the file is just called `.bash_functions` the colorizing doesn't happen - because the file extension is not known.

Is there any way I can get `color-highlight` to color dot files (files that begin with a dot) as `sh` colors ?

btw this builds on top of [How can i colorize cat output including unknown filetypes in b&w?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/100841/10043)

`man source-higlight` shows the following but I'm not clear what to do:

```
...
--outlang-def=filename
      output language definition file

--outlang-map=filename
      output language map file (default=`outlang.map')

--data-dir=path
      directory where language definition files and language maps are searched for.   If  not  specified
      these files are searched for in the current directory and in the data dir installation directory

--output-dir=path
      output directory

--lang-def=filename
      language definition file

--lang-map=filename
      language map file  (default=`lang.map')

--show-lang-elements=filename
      prints the language elements that are defined

      in the language definition file

--infer-lang
      force to infer source script language (overriding given language specification)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `cdc` function as

```
cdc() {
    for fn do
        if [[ "${fn##*/}" == .* ]]
        then
            source-highlight --src-lang=sh --out-format=esc -i "$fn"
        else
            source-highlight               --out-format=esc -i "$fn"
        fi 2> /dev/null  ||  /bin/cat "$fn"
    done
}
```

- `for fn do` is short for `for fn in "$@"; do`.
- `${fn##*/}` looks at the value of `$fn` and removes
  everything from the beginning up through (and including) the last `/`. 
  I.e., if `$fn` is a full pathname, this will be just the filename part.
- `[[ (the_above) == .* ]]` checks
  whether the filename matches the `.*` glob/wildcard pattern;
  i.e., whether the filename begins with a **`.`**. 
  Note that this usage of `==` works only inside `[[ … ]]`;
  it does not work inside `[ … ]`.
- So, if `$fn` is a “dot file”,
  run `source-highlight` with the `--src-lang=sh` option.

  - You should always put shell variable references in double quotes
    unless you have a good reason not to,
    and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. 
    Unix/Linux filenames can contain spaces. 
    If you had a file named `foo bar`, and you said `/bin/cat "foo bar"`,
    `cat` would display the contents of the file `foo bar`. 
    But, if you said `cdc "foo bar"`
    (with the current version of your `cdc` function),
    you would run `source-highlight` with `-i foo bar`,
    which would look for a file called `foo` and generally make a mess of things. 
    And so it would fail, and your function would try `/bin/cat foo bar`,
    which would likewise fail. 
    Using `"$fn"` makes this work for filenames that contain spaces.
  - The `cp` program requires you to specify, on the argument list,
    the name of the file or directory you want it to write to. 
    This is one of the few exceptions to the rule that most programs
    write to standard output by default (unless you specify otherwise). 
    You don’t need to say `-o STDOUT`, and I wonder
    why the author(s) of the program even made it possible for you to specify that.

  And, yes, I realize that you just copied all of that
  from the answer to your other question.
- Obviously, if `$fn` is not a dot file,
  just run `source-highlight` the normal way, and let it check for an extension.
- Note that the `2> /dev/null` and the `||  /bin/cat "$fn"` can be done
  for the `if … then … else … fi` block in its entirety;
  they don’t have to be repeated for each branch.

Hmm.  My version of `source-highlight` (3.1.7)
has a `--src-lang=LANGUAGE` option
(`-s LANGUAGE`, as used by yaegashi, for short). 
I just noticed that it isn’t in the `source-highlight` man page excerpt
you included in your question.  So, obviously,
if your version of `source-highlight` doesn’t support that option,
my answer won’t work for you.  (And, of course, neither will yaegashi’s.) 
If that’s the case, you should see if you can install version 3.1.7
(or compatible) of `source-highlight`.

Comment: This worked for me.  btw I am on `source-highlight v3.1.6`

Comment: Great!  (Maybe you have the wrong version of the man page?)

Answer (score 3):

Specify `-s sh` only when `$fn` looks like a dot file.

```
cdc() {
  for fn in "$@"; do
    OPTIONS="-f esc"
    case "${fn##*/}" in
      .*) OPTIONS="$OPTIONS -s sh" ;;
    esac
    source-highlight $OPTIONS -i "$fn" 2>/dev/null || \cat "$fn"
  done
}
alias cat=cdc
```

You can add other custom file name matching rules in `case`.

Answer (score 3):

[yaegashi has the right idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208042/3645), although I would do it like this:

```
cdc() {
    for path
    do
        command=(source-highlight --out-format=esc -o STDOUT --failsafe)
        case "${path##*/}" in
            .*) command+=(-s sh)
                ;;
        esac
        "${command[@]}" -i "$path"
    done
}
```

- `--failsafe` acts like `cat` if the language can't be detected - much better than ignoring all errors
- Uses an [array for the command arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: The point of the `||  /bin/cat "$fn"` is that `source-highlight --out-format=esc -i some.text` fails with `source-highlight: could not find a language definition for input file some.text`, because `source-highlight` can't figure out what "language" the file is in, so you want the function to fall back to using `cat` without exposing the ugly error message to the user.  But thanks for the reference on using an array for command arguments.

Comment: @Scott Fixed with a fallback option.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to looking at the file extension, source-highlight has some other ways of detecting the language. You could annotate your shell script files like this:

1. The shabang line: put `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` on the first line of the file.
2. Emacs-style file type annotations: add a comment like `# -*- shell -*-` or `# -*- bash -*-` in the file (doesn't need to be the first line).

For details, see [*How the input language is discovered*](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html#How-the-input-language-is-discovered) in source-highlight's manual.